# How to set a DropDown List value taken from a promise with a value taken from another promise

Tags: angularjs, pug, angular-promise

I want to understand how to successfully set a value inside a DropDown List after it has been populated by a promise. The value to be set will be taken from another promise which will fill a form with a JSON structure.

In my particular case the incidence is as follows

The Drop-Down List is built as :

1) HTML Template (Jade)

```
select(name="inputUserRelationship",
       ng-model="myForm.relationship",
       ng-options="relationshipOption as relationshipOption.value for relationshipOption in relationships track by relationshipOption.id",
       ng-init="myForm.insuredRelationship = relationships[0]")
    option(value="") -- SELECT --
```

2) Controller:

```
$scope.getRelationTypes = function(){
 HttpSrv.get('api/getRelationTypes/').then(function(results){
    $scope.relationships = results;
 }); };
```

The form gets filled in the Controller as follows:

```
$scope.getFormInformation = function(ID){
HttpSrv.get('/api/getFormInfo/' + ID).then(function(results){
  if(results)
  {
    $scope.fillForm(results);
  }
}); };

$scope.fillForm = function(filledFormData){
     $scope.myForm.relationship = filledFormData.relationnshipID; };
```

This produces the following issues on my JS Debugging Console:

1. The value gets set on the model
2. The Drop-Down List stays on the default empty value ([0]).
3. When I try to change the selected option on my Drop-Down list it then produces the following JS Console Error.

> **TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'id' of 9**
>       at setter (vendor.js:42989)
>       at Lexer.readIdent.token.fn.extend.assign (vendor.js:42424)
>       at validationErrorKey.$setViewValue (vendor.js:49629)
>       at vendor.js:53523
>       at Scope.promises.$get.Scope.$eval (vendor.js:44729)
>       at Scope.promises.$get.Scope.$apply (vendor.js:44827)
>       at HTMLSelectElement. (vendor.js:53465)
>       at HTMLSelectElement.jQuery.event.dispatch (vendor.js:4641)
>       at HTMLSelectElement.jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle (vendor.js:4309)

Any information is greatly appreciated. I have already researched & tested the **$scope.apply()** and **$q** options and neither have been successful to me even though I know they point to the right direction.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

if your $http API call returns an json in the format:

```
[{"id":"1", "value":"Dropdown desc"}, {...}, {}]
```

You should set an object literal with the same structure to set the dropdownlist to a specific values like:

```
$scope.myForm.relationship = {"id":"1", "value":"Dropdown desc"};
```